# I was trying to pick Books value from dropdown on ebay categories dropdown, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong. I keep getting error

Tags: powershell, selenium, dropdown

```
 $workingPath = 'C:\Selenium'

 $env:Path += ";$workingPath"

 Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\WebDriver.dll"

 $ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver

 $temp = $ChromeDriver.Navigate()
 $temp.GoToURL('https://www.ebay.com')

 $ChromeDriver.FindElementById("gh-cat").Click()
 $Value = '267'
 $SelectElement = [OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement]::new($DropDown)
 $SelectElement.SelectByValue('267')
```

This is my Code, the value of what i am trying to select is 267 and its the books option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Powershell syntax very well but it looks like you are trying to find the first element by `ID`: `$ChromeDriver.FindElementById("gh-cat").Click()`

The problem with that is there are 3 of those `"gh-cat"` ID's on that page.  It does not reference a single element.

What happens if you try `$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("_sacat").Click()` instead? Find by `Name` instead of `ID`. That references the dropdown menu and is unique.  That action would click it, and then you would Select by the Value you want, 267 in your case.

Not sure if this will work, but worth a shot

Comment: I appreciate the answer but IDs are usually unique to an element.